# How to break out data into separate files?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to break out an Excel data table into unique files based on a project name in column A.
For example, In the table below I need to break out three separate files (Project A, Project B, and Project C).
[image: Table Example]

I have VBA code to separate the files into separate tabs, but not separate files.

```vb
Sub Break_Out()
    
    Const col = "A"
    Const header_row = 1
    Const starting_row = 2
    
    Dim source_sheet As Worksheet
    Dim destination_sheet As Worksheet
    Dim source_row As Long
    Dim last_row As Long
    Dim destination_row As Long
    Dim Project As String
    
    Set source_sheet = ActiveSheet
    last_row = source_sheet.Cells(source_sheet.Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Row
    For source_row = starting_row To last_row
        Project = source_sheet.Cells(source_row, col).Value
        Set destination_sheet = Nothing
        On Error Resume Next
    
        Set destination_sheet = Worksheets(Project)
        On Error GoTo 0
    
        If destination_sheet Is Nothing Then
            Set destination_sheet = Worksheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
            destination_sheet.Name = Project
            source_sheet.Rows(header_row).Copy Destination:=destination_sheet.Rows(header_row)
    
        End If
        destination_row = destination_sheet.Cells(destination_sheet.Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        source_sheet.Rows(source_row).Copy Destination:=destination_sheet.Rows(destination_row)
    
    Next source_row
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way, using a Dictionary to track the workbooks created during the run

```vb
Sub Break_Out()

    Const col = "A"
    Const header_row = 1
    Const starting_row = 2
    
    Dim source_sheet As Worksheet
    Dim source_row As Long
    Dim last_row As Long
    Dim Project As String
    Dim dict As Object
    
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Set source_sheet = ActiveSheet
    last_row = source_sheet.Cells(source_sheet.Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Row
    For source_row = starting_row To last_row
        
        Project = source_sheet.Cells(source_row, col).Value
        
        If Len(Project) > 0 Then
            'add a new workbook if one doesn't already exist
            If Not dict.exists(Project) Then
                Set dict(Project) = Workbooks.Add()
                dict(Project).Worksheets(1).Name = Project
                'optionally save to a specific location...
            End If
            'copy row to relevant sheet
            source_sheet.Rows(source_row).Copy _
                dict(Project).Worksheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        
        End If
    Next source_row

End Sub
```

Comment: Brilliant: *Utilizing the full potential of the dictionary*, one might say. I knew it could hold objects, but I didn't know how. Now I know. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

### Dictionary to Collect Workbook Names

- This code basically only implements a dictionary object into the initial code, to collect the worksheet names (values of the `Project` variable) and after the code has created the worksheets, moves them to files getting saved as `Project A.xlsx`, `Project B.xlsx` and `Project C.xlsx` in a specified folder, in this case in `"F:\Test\2020\64862938\"`.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Break_Out()

    Const fPath As String = "F:\Test\2020\64862938\"
    Const sCol As String = "A"
    Const dCol As String = "A"
    Const hRow As Long = 1
    Const fRow As Long = 2
    
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim src As Worksheet
    Dim dst As Worksheet
    Dim dict As Object ' ***
    Dim Key As Variant ' ***
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim dRow As Long
    Dim Project As String
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' The workbook containing this code.
    Set src = wb.ActiveSheet ' Set src = wb.worksheets("Sheet1") is better.
    lRow = src.Cells(src.Rows.Count, sCol).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") ' ***
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    For i = fRow To lRow
        
        Project = "Project " & src.Cells(i, sCol).Value
        Set dst = Nothing
        On Error Resume Next
        Set dst = wb.Worksheets(Project)
        On Error GoTo 0
        
        If dst Is Nothing Then
            Set dst = wb.Worksheets.Add(After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count))
            dst.Name = Project
            dict(Project) = Empty ' ***
            src.Rows(hRow).Copy Destination:=dst.Rows(hRow)
        End If
        dRow = dst.Cells(dst.Rows.Count, dCol).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        src.Rows(i).Copy Destination:=dst.Rows(dRow)
    
    Next i
    
    ' Move worksheets to files.
    For Each Key In dict.Keys ' ***
        wb.Worksheets(Key).Move ' ***
        With ActiveWorkbook
            ' This will overwrite the previous versions.
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            .SaveAs Filename:=fPath & Key, _
                    FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook ' .xlsx ' ***
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            .Close SaveChanges:=False
        End With
    Next Key ' ***
    
    wb.Save
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    MsgBox "Worksheets created.", vbInformation, "Success"
    
End Sub
```

Comment: This worked great! One question, is there any way to maintain the source formatting on the workbooks generated?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Could you describe exactly what is wrong with the output?

Comment: The output is generating correctly. However, the column width, row width, etc get overridden to the default workbook settings. Is there a way to adjust this to match the format of the source table?

Comment: You could use [Range.PasteSpecial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.pastespecial) when you will have [these additional options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlpastetype). The first line would be `src.Rows(i).Copy`. The other lines would be `dst.Rows(hRow).PasteSpecial`, `dst.Rows(hRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths`... and usually this line is followed: `Application.CutCopyMode = False`. Maybe a better solution would be to copy the whole worksheet and then by filtering the data delete the undesired rows.